# One way that’s lasted: the jack that helps in the changing of a tire

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't understand the meaning of the following phrase. Is the jack in question that's "lasted"? If so, in what way? Does jack here refer to a tool as well? Thank you!

"[One way that’s lasted: the jack that helps in the changing of a tire](https://www.portablepress.com/blog/2019/07/tool-name-origins/#:%7E:text=The%20jackhammer%20got%20its%20name,(and%20breaks%20it%20apart).)."

Comment: One ***way of using the word "Jack"*** that has stood the test of time *(**lasted, endured, continued**)* is in the context of "car-tyre-changing" ***jacks***.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: And it was a genuine question, bu for some reason  I got -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not well written.

The author says that "jack" became a way to talk about any tool or mechanical device.  This was slang, and most of these slang words aren't used anymore (the slang hasn't lasted), but there is one tool that is still called a "jack",  the tool that lifts a car when you need to change a tyre.  It assumes that you know this tool and know it is called "a jack", because reminding you of this will help you understand the meaning of "jackhammer".

If you don't know that "jack" means "a tool for lifting a car" it could be confusing.

Comment: There is a more ribald nuance, I think, that can be clearly seen in a 'jack plug', or the 'jack shafts' (stubby shafts) used in older electric railway locomotives.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!